# IS these equivalences are false or true?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$$d(A,B)=0\Longleftrightarrow A\cap B\neq\emptyset$$

it true where

1- A,B are compact

2- A compact and B closed

3- A, B are closed

I can prove that in cases 1 and 2 if $A\cap B=\emptyset $ then $d(A,B)>0$

but i don't know the rest

please help me

thank you

Comment: The right to left implications are always true regardless of $A$ and $B$. The common point proves $d(A,B)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

This is only true in cases 1 and 2. Note that $d(x,B)$ is a continuous function on a compact set so the minimum is achieved. This is an alternative proof that $A\cap B=\emptyset\implies d(A,B)>0$. To see 3 is not true, consider the graph of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the $x$ axis. These get arbitrarily close, but have no points in common.

Comment: i say that i CAN prove that $A\cap B=\emptyset d(A,B)>0$ my problem is with the other sens

Comment: The other direction is trivial. If $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$, there exists $x\in A\cap B$, so $d(A,B)\le d(x,x)=0$.

Comment: Have I answered all your questions at this point?

Comment: can you please explane me the example please

Comment: Consider the sets $A=\{(x,0):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$, $B=\{(x,\frac{1}{x}):x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\}$ as subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Note that they do not intersect, but $$\lim_{x\to\infty} d\left(\left(x,0\right),\left(x,\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$$ so $d(A,B)=0$.